# Cannot share via bluetooth....file not sent error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth, share

Here is my code:

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent sharingIntent = new  Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
PackageManager pm =getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList =   pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);

for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
    String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
    Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "share");

    if(TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.facebook.katana")){
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http:your link");
    } else {
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  Fragmentactivity.songpaths.get(indexfordelete));
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Thirukural Version 1.7.2 !");
    }
    targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
}

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Share Application  your app name ");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

I am trying to share it via bluetooth firstly but it is not working. I am getting the error ~`File not sent`. `Fragmentactivity.songpaths.get(indexfordelete)` is the path to file i want to share.

Comment: Have you add uses permission?

Comment: yes..i added the permission.but i serached onSO that u need to pass by bytes to share via bluettoth .i am not getting how to do that

Comment: I am not geetting error on eclipse .....i am geeting error on real device like u get while sharing on bluetooth that file not sent

Comment: logcat catch every debug actions, copy part when you click send

Comment: Can u suggest wat code i shud put on logcat so we can understand easily?

Comment: Nothing is tere :( related to my app or bluetooth service

Comment: you start the app  , start the Blootooth and when it leaves the error go on eclipse and saved all logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code  here i sharing a text ,u can share what do you want:

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent sharingIntent = new      Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
PackageManager pm =v.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList =   pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);

for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
    String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
    Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "share");

    if(TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.facebook.katana")){
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http:your link");
    } else {
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strLink);
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " app version");
    }
    targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
}

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Share Application  your app name ");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: It is sending html file not .mp3 file ?

Comment: Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+mypath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));                                  try this @developer

Comment: or else this will helping you                                                                  String sharePath =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File")); @developer

Comment: Thanx but none of them worked.........but frm SO other posts i got it working..still thanx for helping me out :)